# Send JSON in query String

Tags: java, json, facebook, httpclient

Am trying to login to my web application using facebook, it was working okey till recently I started getting this error

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 43: https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={"access_token":"E","token_type":"bearer"}
```

Am trying to solve it using the below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String accessToken = "{\"access_token\":\"E\",\"token_type\":\"bearer\"}";
        try {

            //String urlStr = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(accessToken,"UTF-8");
            String urlStr = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" +accessToken;
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlStr);
            httpget.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Also tried using post request

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String accessToken = "{\"access_token\":\"E\",\"token_type\":\"bearer\"}";
        try {

            //String urlStr = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(accessToken,"UTF-8");
            String urlStr = "https://graph.facebook.com/me";
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost(urlStr);
            httpget.setEntity(new StringEntity("access_token="+accessToken));
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But it produces the below exception

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractResponseHandler.handleResponse(AbstractResponseHandler.java:69)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:222)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:139)
    at com.simsarak.servlet.facebook.FacebookLogin.main(FacebookLogin.java:178)
```

Tried to use the `URLEncoder` and setting headers to `application/json` but still not working, What could be the problem ?

Comment: Why won't you put it into the request body??

Comment: produces bad request, tried with different combination of headers and encoding

Comment: Where exactly is it failing?  How about presenting the stack trace that goes with that exception?

Comment: You led off with a question about a `URISyntaxException`, but presented the stack trace of an `HttpResponseException`.  The only way that makes any sense is if the former is the "cause" wrapped by the latter. In any case, to be useful, a stack trace must include the portions describing any and all wrapped exceptions.

Comment: In any case, neither the generic URI syntax nor the specific URL syntax permit the characters `{`, `}`, or `:` to appear in the literally query string, so at minimum it is essential to urlencode those characters in the value of the `access_token` query parameter.  Although your program might still not work when you do that, does it really produce the same exception in that event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it appears that I have now to extract only the access token from the json and send it alone, I've done this by

```
private String getUserMailAddressFromJsonResponse(String accessToken, HttpSession httpSession) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {

            if (accessToken != null && !"".equals(accessToken)) {
                json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(accessToken);
                String newUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + json.get("access_token");
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(newUrl);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
...
```